# I need this linux port forwarding command translated to putty

Tags: windows-7, linux, ssh, putty

How can I translate this command to putty? I'm on a windows machine running putty.

```
ssh -f HOST_A.net.local -L 2000:HOST_F.net.loal:3306 -N
```

I'm following along with these links. But the `-f` flag doesn't seem to be represented.

http://www.cs.uu.nl/technical/services/ssh/putty/puttyfw.html
http://www.akadia.com/services/ssh_putty.html

I'm either too dense or too sleep deprived (or both) to figure this out right now.

Answer (score 4):

```
plink HOST_A.net.local -L 2000:HOST_F.net.loal:3306 -N
```

There's no `-f` flag because neither PuTTY nor `plink` support detaching to background.